# Merging HTML texts having exactly the same style

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have two consecutive divs with exactly the same style which give a different result if their texts are combined into one?
So suppose we have:

```
var x = ""; //any valid string of css attributes except "display"
var style = "display:inline;" + x;

var content1 = "<div style='" + style + "'>123</div><div style='" + style + "'>456</div>";

var content2 = "<div style='" + style + "'>123456</div>";
```

Now we do either

```
document.getElementById("D").innerHTML = content1;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("D").innerHTML = content2;
```

Is it certain that, however x is chosen (without changing the display:inline), in either case the same result will be displayed in D? 
If it's true, it's like an elementary theorem in HTML! But how does one go on to prove such statements?

In view of the persuasive examples given in the first comment and the first answer below, I have to add that I mean to exclude stylings that "violently" alter the position of the two divs... if that's not too vague, and focus only on "structural" attributes, like fonts, colors, decorations etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "a different result"?   If you're talking about the layout then of course it could differ; the divs could be padded or not.

Comment: Yes obviously... So the question needs to be improved, perhaps.

Comment: I would say so, yes. It’s not clear to me what you’re trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2):

If that theory statement was true, then it would be hard to prove. However, it isn't, and it is easy to come up with cases that disprove it.

For example:

## Floats

```css
.example { overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<h1>Floats</h1>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; float: right;">foo</div>
    <div style="display: inline; float: right;">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; float: right;">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

## Margins

```css
.example { overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<h1>Margins</h1>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; margin: 5em;">foo</div>
    <div style="display: inline; margin: 5em;">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; margin: 5em;">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

## Flex ancestors

```css
.example { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<h1>Flex ancestors</h1>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline;">foo</div>
    <div style="display: inline;">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline;">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

## Positioning

```css
.example { position: relative; height: 20px;}
```

```html
<h1>Positioning</h1>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">foo</div>
    <div style="display: inline; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">bar</div>
</div>

<div class="example">
    <div style="display: inline; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for these examples. I put the "display:inline" trying to exclude styles that alter the "sequential" placement of the two divs, and focus only to those that do "structural" modifications, like font-styles,  colors, etc.. Do you think the question does have meaning if we manage somehow to formally exclude the position-related styles?

Comment: The question then becomes a tautological “If we exclude everything that could affect the element position, would the position always be the same?”

Comment: but it's not only about position. If a gradient background is applied,. then obviously it makes a difference if the texts are separated or merged!